How to control the position of a tool window's search control?
I am developing a WPF Visual Studio 2022 extension. It contains a ToolWindowPane and a custom UserControl I am developing. I would like to add the "standard" VS search control to my control.
Reading through the below article: Add search to a tool window I found out the VS provides its native control to use, But the control position is always at top of the tool pane and expand its horizontal size.
How can i position this control as part of my control? (inside a grid cell with other UI positioning attributes)

What about using IVsWindowSearchHostFactory to create one and make the search window element in your control in xaml design?

@BowmanZhu-MSFT: can you provide an example of how to use it?
